# Adding 20 minutes to number in java

Tags: java, java-7

So I need a variable that shows times in 24HR format (01:00, 09:00) and every time I loop through it, to add 20 mins to the time? I then need to use this value in a string.

The time needs to start at any given time. like 00:00
Any ideas how should I go with it?

and output like this 00:00-00:20,00:20-..00:40,00:40-01:00 and so on....

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will print timestamps in `HH:mm` format for each 20 minutes:

```
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
System.out.println(dt.format(df));
for (int i = 0; i < 24 * 3; i++) {
    dt = dt.plusMinutes(20);
    System.out.println(dt.format(df));
}
```

Its output is as follows:

```
00:00
00:20
00:40
01:00
01:20
...
```

**Update**

Sorry, it could be done with simple loop:

```
for (int min = 0; min < 24 * 60; min += 20) {
    int next = min + 20;
    String timestamp = String.format("%02d:%02d - %02d:%02d", min/60, min%60, next/60, next%60);
    System.out.println(timestamp);
}
/////
00:00 - 00:20
00:20 - 00:40
00:40 - 01:00
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.I have already done this.  But i want to sort my data like this 

00:00-00:20
00:20-00:40
00:40-01:00

Can you help me in sorting in this way.

Comment: The code is giving below error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.time.temporal

What can be done to rectify this

Comment: The upper code won't work in Java 7 as it uses `java.time` features available since Java 8. You should use plain loop.

Comment: So how can we do that in java 7 please.

Comment: Meaning?  There is the code after **Update**.  You may need to remove unused `java.time` imports in your code.

Comment: If this answer is ok for you, please mark it as accepted.  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, The answer is fine for me. It has solved my issue. Thank you very much.